# CGo: how to pass a 2 dimensional slice to C function

Tags: go, cgo

My code is:

```
package main

/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <string.h>                                                                                                                                                                                               

void fill_2d_array(char (*s)[16]) {                                                                                                                                                                               
    strcpy(s[0], "hello");                                                                                                                                                                                        
    strcpy(s[1],"cgo");                                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
        dirs := make([][]byte, 4)
        for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
            dirs[i] = make([]byte, 16)
        }
        C.fill_2d_array(((*C.char)[16])(unsafe.Pointer(&dirs)))

        fmt.Println(dirs)
}
```

When I run with `go run test.go`, it failed and said:

```
./test.go:21: type *C.char is not an expression
```

My Question is how to pass a 2 dimensional slice to a C function like `fill_2d_array` above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:
`C.fill_2d_array((*[16]C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&dirs)))`

Comment: This code just passed compile. It crashed when run it. :(